# How to find the shortest path in R?

Tags: r, path, traveling-salesman

I have this symmetrix matrix with the distance between nodes:

```
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
[1,]  0  8  7  6  5  4  3
[2,]  8  0  1  2  3  4  5
[3,]  7  1  0  1  2  3  4
[4,]  6  2  1  0  1  2  3
[5,]  5  3  2  1  0  1  2
[6,]  4  4  3  2  1  0  1
[7,]  3  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

How can I find the path that minimize the total distance?
I need the distance and the tour.
May I use TSP algorithm?(How can I?)

Comment: Have you had a look at `igraph` package? Have a look at this example, may be of use: http://rpubs.com/somasdhavala/GAeg

Comment: @TonyHellmuth I have to modify this code because I want to start from a specific city (eg. Rome) and having as output only three cities. I mean, I have to consider as input all the 21 cities but as output I need only the shortest path composed by 3 cities. (eg.Rome - Milan - Vienna - Rome)